# How to solve ODE's $\dot{x}=ax+by$ and $\dot{y}=bx+cy$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help in solving a system of ODE's $$x'(t)=ax(t)+by(t) \mbox{ and } y'(t)=bx(t)+cy(t)$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y$ denote standard co-ordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I checked on wolfram alpha and the solution looked very complicated.

Comment: It is still the same solution method as when solving a system of ODEs with given coefficients; find eigenvalues, eigenvectors, form general solution. However in this case your eigenvalues and eigenvectors are just going to be messy.. for the eigenvalues I got $$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{(c+a)\pm\sqrt{(c-a)^{2}+4b^{2}}}{2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give the idea, since the calculations really seems a pain. Let: $$X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{pmatrix}, \quad \mbox{and} \quad A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now your system is $X'(t) = A \cdot X(t)$. The idea is to diagonalize $A$. Since $A$ is symmetric, we're good. The characteristic polynomial is $p(t) = t^2 - (a+c)t + (ac -b^2)$. So the eigenvalues are: $$\lambda_\pm = \frac{a+c \pm \sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}}{2}.$$

If $a=c$ and $b = 0$, then $x(t) = C_1 e^{at}$ and $y(t) = C_2e^{at}$, for $C_1,C_2 \in \Bbb R$. Otherwise, you must find bases for the eigenspaces, that is, find some vectors ${\bf v}_+$ and ${\bf v}_-$ such that $(A - \lambda_+{\rm Id}){\bf v}_+ = 0$ and $(A - \lambda_-{\rm Id}){\bf v}_- = 0$. So your solution will be $$X(t) = C_1 e^{\lambda_+t}{\bf v}_+ + C_2e^{\lambda_-t}{\bf v}_-, \quad C_1,C_2 \in \Bbb R.$$